# jquery/javascript hide and show element depend dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show/hide options on one select drop down dependant on another drop down's selected option.

I mean , when i choose  "Other" then will show on anther drop down full list (male & female) !! 
and when i choose "mr. engineer" then will show  just "Male" 
and when i choose "miss. engineer" then will show  just "female".

```
<select>
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr. Engineer</option>
<option value="Miss">Miss. Engineer</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>

</select>

<select>
<!--Below shows when 'Other' is selected , and show otherwise-->
<option value="0">choose</option>

<!--Below shows when 'Mr. engineer' is selected jsut , and hidden otherwise-->
<option value="male">Male</option>

<!--Below shows when 'Miss. engineer' is selected just, and hidden otherwise-->
<option value="female">Female</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` and do:

```
$("#dropdownlist").change(function() {
   var control = $(this);

   if (control.val() == "Engineer") {
      $("#dropdownlist2").show();
   }
});
```

This is based on the following structure:

```
<select id="dropdown1">
   <option value="Mechanic">Mechanic </option>
   <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
 </select>

<select id="dropdown2" style="display:none">
   <option value="Item 1">Item 1 </option>
   <option value="Item 2">Item 2 </option>
 </select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zs3QG/

Answer (score 0):

In such situations, I usually resort to mapping values between the selects in the HTML itself and using those mappings from JS instead of hard-wiring it in JS.

For example: The `appliesto` attribute maps options in select2 that are applicable to each option in select1.

```
<select id="one">
  <option>Choose</option>
  <option appliesto="male">Mr. Engineer</option>
  <option appliesto="female">Miss. Engineer</option>
  <option appliesto="other">Other</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
  <option type="other">choose</option>
  <option type="male">Male</option>
  <option type="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

And use those mapping to show/hide as needed via JS.

```
$('select#one').change(function() {
    var selType = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('appliesto');
    $('select#two option[type="'+selType+'"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xGJRP/1/

Of course you might need to fine tune this further, but i believe you get the idea.

Comment: ** i mean , when i choose "Other" then will show on anther drop down 
full list (female & male) !!

and when i choose "mr. engineer" then will show a Male just
and so on . . . 
**

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly, check out the updated demo too.